# Proving in Discrete Structures Problem that $2^N = \binom{N}{0} + \binom{N}{1} + \binom{N}{2} + \dots + \binom{N}{N}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Here's how it is.  So I was studying some notes on Discrete Structures then I discovered this. Prove that $2^N = \binom{N}{0} + \binom{N}{1} + \binom{N}{2} + \dots + \binom{N}{N}$ Since I was new to this, I didn't quite understand it.  I tried using the binomial expansion but it confused me a little.  Can someone please help me solve this.  That would be great.

Comment: By `(N, 0)`, do you mean $N \choose 0$? Also, does it stop at $N \choose 11$ or does it go all the way up to $N \choose N$?

Comment: Look at the review history: I was the last editor :). Btw I also changed `\choose` to `\binom`. `\choose` (as all TeX-style fraction commands) are obsolete and should not be used anymore. Just for the record. `{N\choose0}` -> `\binom{N}{0}`. And don't worry for missing that :).

Comment: To clarify: "that" referred to the 11, not the obsolete command change. [Here](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/technote.pdf) it is explained why one should avoid such commands.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that $N\in \mathbb{N}$, and by $(N,x)$ you meant $\binom{N}{x}$ then

$$
2^N = (1+1)^N = \sum_{x=0}^N\binom{N}{x}1^x1^{N-x} = \sum_{x=0}^N\binom{N}{x}
$$

Answer (score 1):

I am giving a combinatorial proof.

Consider a set $S$ with $n$ elements, i.e. #$\color{blue}{S=n}$.

Now, try to count the number subsets we can form.

It, is easily found that number of $1$-subsets is $\color{blue}{n\choose 1}$, number of $2$-subsets is $\color{blue}{n\choose 2}$, $\dots$, number of $n$-subsets is $\color{blue}{n\choose n}$, and the number of null subset is $\color{blue}{n\choose 0}$ .

So, the total number of subsets is $$\color{blue}{{n\choose 0}+{n\choose 1}+{n\choose 2}+\dots+{n\choose n}}.$$

Now, try to count another way. Suppose that we have a basket containing subsets of $S$. Now pick up each elements of $S$ and we have $2$ choices to place them, in the basket of back to the set $S$. So, for every element, there are $2$ choices, so, number of ways is $\color{blue}{2^n}$.

Now, *since we counted the same thing in two different ways, so the different expressions we got must be equal.*

So,$$\color{red}{{n\choose 0}+{n\choose 1}+{n\choose 2}+\dots+{n\choose n}=2^n}.$$